# Sorting objects by value 1, 0 -1 in reference to other object 

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, comparison, view

I've got a function in my sort that compare row 1 and row two, then check condition (that i must write) - "The comparison code must return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero if the first row should respectively appear before, stay where it was compared to, or appear after the second row."

Ive got a two variables, color 1, and color 2.
I want to sort things like:

First color 1, than color 2, than everything else.

What condition I must write to do that?
Ive tried something like that but is not working.
$row1 - first element 
$row2 - second element

```
if(COLOR 1 == $row1->name)
   return -1;
if(COLOR 2 == $row1->name &&  $row2->name != COLOR 2)
     return 0;
else if(COLOR 2 == $row2->name && $row2->name == COLOR 1)
   return -1;
else return 1;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: 'row' immplies database - if you're using a database then there's no good reason for sorting your data in php.

Comment: Is this code contained in a function being passed to `usort()`?

Comment: yes I know, but my drupal function in PHP Views module require to sort things by return a variable.

Comment: @cillosis I think its like in usort. I must implement it in my drupal module function. Return value of this condition is like in usort

Answer (score 1):

How do you want to decide whether a color is greater or less than another color?
When using callback functions for sorting (like what PHP's usort() function requires), the function should return 0 if $color1 and $color2 are equal, -1 if $color1 is less than $color2, and 1 if $color1 is greater than $color2

```
function cmp ( $color1, $color2 ){
  if($color1 < $color2){  /* or some other test for inequality */
    return -1;
  }else if($color1 > $color2){  /* again, it is up to you to define the "values" of colors */
    return 1;
  }else{  /* the colors are equal */
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: I want to decide it like:
if my row->color == COLOR 1 Then it must be first because we compare color 1.
if row ->color == COLOR 2 Then it must be after the all COLOR 1 things
and then all of rest